# A question about variable reference in chained XSLTs

Tags: xml, xslt

I think this is a beginner question, it is regarding the variable references across different XSLT templates. The structure is like this:

I firstly have an XSLT file, and in it, I've declared an template A, and within it, I basically loop through each record(row) of an XML file, say, xml_A, and I've declared a variable to refer to a particular field called "id" of the current record in xml_A. Then, within this for-each loop, I need to call another template B.

```
 <xsl:template name="A">
 <LoopA> 
    <xsl:for-each select="$xml_A//xml_A_row">
    <xsl:variable name="id_A" select="id"/>
     ....
 </LoopA>
 <xsl:call-template name="B"/> 
 </xsl:template>
```

For template B, I actually created another XSLT file under the same directory. The B contains millions of records from xml file "xml_B", but I only want the records that have the SAME id field as the current record of template A. Here is how I did it:

```
<xsl:template name="B">
<LoopB>
<xsl:variable name="id_A" select="id"/>
 ...
</loopB>
</xsl:template>
```

Here comes my question. I used the above `<xsl:variable name="id_A" select="id"/>` to refer to the id field of the current record that the upper loop is on. However, I am not sure whether this is correct, I've done some testing, since the data file is so huge, thus it is not easy to visually test if this is doing the right thing.

So I wonder if anybody could advise if the above reference to variable of the outer-loop is correct since if I delete that, the XML editor will complain.

Thanks in advance.

**Update from comments**

> I think I didn't make it clear enough.
>   Actually neither `xml_A` or `xml_B` is the
>   xml files that are going to be XSLTed.
>   They are just data files which I will
>   use to pull data from, and there's
>   another XML file C that is used as for
>   applying the stylesheet on and it is
>   empty. So in my style sheet, using
>   the provide answer, I must have a way to
>   make it refer to this data storage
>   file xml_A.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are those `loopA` and `loopB` elements doing into the stylesheet fragment?

Comment: @Aljandro: LoopA and LoopB are just tags that will be shown in the output xml.

Comment: If `LoopA` and `LoopB` are *literal result elements*, then they can't have a functional `xsl:template` element as content. Please, show us the complete stylesheet.

Comment: @Aljandro: thanks for the note. I found out it was a typo for the code, I already moidified the code, is the one now OK? I've test it in XML Spy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical XSLT style would be:

```
<xsl:variable name="xml_B" select="document('xml_B.xml')">

<xsl:template match="xml_A_row">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$xml_B/path/to/xml_B_row[id = current()/id]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**: Pattern matching instead of `xsl:for-each` and named templates, `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:call-template`, `current()` function to reference context node.

**EDIT**: In order to look more like your incomplete stylesheet fragment...

```
<xsl:key name="kBRowById" match="xml_B_row" use="id"/>

<xsl:variable name="xml_A" select="document('xml_A.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="xml_B" select="document('xml_B.xml')"/>

<xsl:template name="A">
  <LoopA>
      <xsl:for-each select="$xml_B">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kBRowById',$xml_A//xml_A_row/id)"
                               mode="just-in-case"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </LoopA>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xml_B_row" mode="just-in-case">
  <LoopB/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**: Using `xsl:key` because you wrote "millons of records", `xsl:for-each` with singleton root node in order to change context node for `fn:key()` function, using outer most scope variable `$xml_A` for cross reference key value. The `mode` is there just in case there is conflic with other rules of the stylesheet you didn't provide.

Comment: @Nic Gibson: Good point! I'm going to extend the explanation in case this is what the OP is asking for...

Comment: @Alejandro: Should it be "match=$xml_A//xml_A_row"?

Comment: @Robert: Variable references can't be used in patterns. Updating my answer in order to look more like your example.

Comment: @Alejandro: I think I didn't make it clear enough. Actually neither xml_A or xml_B is the xml files that are going to be XSLTed. They are just data files which I will use to pull data from, and there's another XML file C that is used as for applying the stylesheet on and it is empty. So in my style sheet, using your code above, I must have a way to make it refer to this data storage file xml_A.

Comment: @Alejandro - I thought you explained fairly well anyway!

Comment: @Flack: Ja! Even in a foreign language.